# How to hide Java public abstract class field?

Tags: java, json, hide

Is it possible to hide in Json `getCount()`? I need to use it in my code for counting, but don't want to see it in Json. I wanted to use `transient`, but for `public abstract` it doesn't allow. Any ideas how can I reach my goal?

`public abstract class` code:

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Plan that) {
        BigDecimal thisValue = this.getCount();
        if (thisValue == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        BigDecimal thatValue = that.getCount();
        if (thatValue == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return thisValue.compareTo(thatValue);
    }

public abstract BigDecimal getCount();
```

And another `public class` with code:

```
@Override
public final BigDecimal getCount() {
    if (exists != null) {
        return plan.getCount();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Which json library do you use? If you use jackson, did you try putting `@JsonIgnore` on the method(either abstract or concrete implementation)? If you use something else did you try its' `@JsonIgnore` equivalent.

Comment: @Chaosfire Hey. How can I check which one json library I have?

Comment: Depends on your build tool, `pom.xml` for maven, `build.gradle` for gradle, if it's something else i don't know. Keep in mind it's probably transitive dependency, so it might not be directly visible.